# Generating bruteforce permutations in C deterministically

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, permutation

I'm working on writing a bruteforce hashcracker in C.

I would like to generate permutations of arbitrary symbols for obvious reasons. However, I also want to be able to "restart" generating permutations from a given point; ie it needs to be serializable or deterministic (not sure what the word is).

So for example, if the symbols were just a-z, it would look something like this:

```
perm(1)  => 'a'
perm(2)  => 'b'
perm(27) => 'aa'
perm(28) => 'ab'
```

and so forth.

Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with c so working out the logic is a little tricky. I think I want to count the number of characters in the current permutation - let's say we're trying to find the next permutation after 'aa'. Since we have two characters, we start by dividing by 26^1 = 26, and find that we can divide once with one remainder. This would imply that the leftmost character should be a and the rightmost character should be a+1 = b, giving us 'ab'. However this is a little tricky: if we start with "az", we need to transform to "ba", and if we start with "zz", we need to transform to "aaa".

Without the requirement to be able to start off from a given point, I would just use a bunch of for loops.

My datatype is a char*, so in a case where we need to prepend a new character to find the next permutation, does that mean we need to allocate new memory for the char* (since it's gaining a character)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't see why you go from `az` to `bz` and not from `az` to `ba`. When would the sequence `ba` to `by` be done?

Comment: I don't see why "bz" follows "az", that doesn't make sense. Without that you're just printing a number. But instead of using the symbols '0', '1', ... you're using symbols 'a', 'b', ... Instead of base 10, you're using base 26.

Comment: Hi, you guys are correct. "az" should transform to "ba". I will edit the original post.

Comment: I don't understand why you need divisions and remainders. You can start with any value you like, say `ceezq` and increment the last character value. As each character reaches `z` it restarts at `a` and increases the preceding character. When you reach `zzzzz` you restart with `aaaaaa`. No need to keep allocating more memory, just use an array that is large enough in the first place. It's just like counting with digits.

Comment: These are called combinations. Permutations are something else.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did a poor job explaining it, but there are two components. The first is generating the permutations one step at a time, ie going 'a'->'b'->'c'...->'z' and so on. The second part is being able to start with a number, say 710, and fast forward to step 710 (the 710th output) and then begin proceeding as normal. Basically in my hashcracker every X hash computations the program outputs to a log file so that if the process is terminated at a bad time, it can be restarted at the correct point. (Also, does anyone know how to do newlines on SO?)

Comment: Then why don't you save the actual combination to a log file and make life easy?

Comment: It looks like you want a ranking/unranking algorithm for permutations. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation

Comment: @gilleain: No, what the OP calls "permutations" is really a [base-26 bijective numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) similar to the one used to identify columns in spreadsheets.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you want to take a string and add 1 so that 'a'+1 results in 'b' and 'z'+1 results in 'a' and a carrier for the next digit. In case there is no "next digit", you want a new digit with the value 'a'.

It can be implemented in many ways. The approach below is just like a simple ripple carrier add.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

void nextValue(char* current)
{
    char a[MAX] = { 0 };
    size_t len = strlen(current);
    if (len >= MAX-1)
    {
        printf("Input too long\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t i;
    char carry = 1;
    for(i=0; i<len;++i)
    {
        char temp = carry+current[len-1-i];
        if (temp > 'z')
        {
            carry = 1;
            a[i] = 'a';
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
            a[i] = temp;
        }

    }
    if (carry)
    {
        a[i] = 'a';
    }

    len = strlen(a);
    for(i=0; i<len;++i)
    {
        current[i] = a[len-1-i];
    }

}

int main(void) {
    char p[MAX] = "az";
    printf("%s\n", p);
    nextValue(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach - and probably better performing approach - is to check the input string for 'z' starting from the last character. Only in case all characters are 'z', it will be required to insert an 'a' in front. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

void nextValue(char* current)
{
    size_t len = strlen(current);
    size_t i = len - 1;
    while(i > 0 && current[i] == 'z')
    {
      current[i] = 'a';
      --i;
    }
    if (i > 0 || current[0] != 'z')
    {
      ++current[i];
      return;
    }
    current[0] = 'a';

    if (len == MAX-1)
    {
      // No more space
      return;
    }

    // Place a new 'a' in front of current
    memmove(current+1, current, len+1);
    current[0] = 'a';
}

int main(void) {
    char p[MAX] = "zz";
    printf("%s\n", p);
    nextValue(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite numbers base 26 because there's that pesky zero digit and you need to know how many leading zeroes are there.

Comment: Also tried this approach first, but after a while I realized that the problems you get from handling the zero digit was not worth it, so I changed approach to just changing a string to next string. Much easier.

Comment: Base 10 numbers have 10 digits. They go 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, not 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,00,01... How do you fit 00, 01 etc in this scheme?

Comment: @n.m. Now I got your point. You are right. Changed that part.

Answer (score -1):

Not EXACTLY what you requested, but it gets the job done. It will (given enough time) produce all possible strings with letters a-z. It is also fulfills your request to be able to continue where you stopped. However, you will not get a number to restart it from. You have to use a string instead.

This is a very fast approach. Since you mentioned you want to use this for brute force, it is much better than converting a number to a string. In the majority of the cases (96%) the only operation will be incrementing a character.

```
void next(char *s)
{
    if(*s == 'z') {
        *s='a';
        next(s+1);
    } else if(*s == 0)
        *s='a';
    else
        (*s)++;
}
```

It takes a string `s` and assumes it is on the form that it starts with an arbitrary number of letters a-z and then is padded with zeros. No error checking is done.

I tested it with this main:

```
char s[30]="a"; 
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    printf("%s ", s);
    next(s);
}
```

Output:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ba ca da ea fa ga ha ia ja ka la ma na oa pa qa ra sa ta ua va wa xa ya za ab bb cb db eb fb gb hb ib jb kb lb mb nb ob pb qb rb sb tb ub vb wb xb yb zb ac bc cc dc ec fc gc hc ic jc kc lc mc nc oc pc qc rc sc tc uc vc
```

Comment: Right now I'm logging the # of attempts (hash computations) performed every interval, but I could easily change it to output the current string. This solution does exactly what I need. If I wanted to have it go from aa->ab instead, would it take longer? Also in the final else block, how does the incrementing of a c-style string work? Is that what makes it go from, say, aa->ba?

Comment: Changing it to aa->ab is not hard, but unless you really need it it complicates things. Rewriting the `next` function would involve moving the whole current string as soon as you add a new character. A hackish workaround would be to write in the middle of a char array and keep track of where it starts. A third option is to simply reverse the string afterwards with some function. But as you see, unless you need it it's unnecessary work that only makes the code more complex and likely slower without any real gain.

Comment: What I do in the final else block is simply incrementing the character `s` points to, so yes, that is what makes it go from aa to ba.